# Sub menu in nativebase react native

Tags: react-native, native-base

Can anyone please let me know how can I create Drawer with submenu in react native using nativebase? I tried few things but they are not working as expected.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Few working examples posted on https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1483
with desired output